# Extracting CSVs from each subdirectory and placing at same level as subdirectory - OS Module

Tags: python

I have a directory like below that contains about 50 'SubDir' but each SubDir only contains 2 SubSubDirs (what I am calling them):

```
Parent Directory
 |
 +-- SubDir #1
 |   |  
 |   +-- SubSubDir #1
 |       |
 |       +-- file1.csv
 |       
 |   +-- SubSubDir #2
 |       |
 |       +-- file2.csv
 |
 +-- SubDir #2
 |   |  
 |   +-- SubSubDir #1
 |       |
 |       +-- file1.csv
 |       
 |   +-- SubSubDir #2
 |       |
 |       +-- file2.csv
 .
 .
 .
```

I need to extract each csv and place at the same level as SubSubDir #1 and #2. I have a script working that walks through each, but all CSVs are being placed right under the Parent Directory, because I cannot figure out how to incorporate a moving destination with os module.

```
rootdir = "/Users/Downloads/Test"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.csv'):
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root,f), rootdir)
```

I know I have rootdir in the code above, which is why the CSVs are being placed right under the rootdir.

Anyone have any insight how to change destination of CSV copy. I am assuming some way to incorporate a moving destination with os module. So far I have been unsuccessful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the name of the directory the file in question is in, and then find the directory of *that*, and put it in that:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.csv'):
            fullpath = os.path.join(root, f)
            shutil.copy(fullpath, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(fullpath)))
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Worked like a charm. Appreciate the quick answer.